# Getting strange and creepy notification on macOS

Tags: macos, safari, virus

I'm using a Macbook Pro, Apple M1, Monterey. Recently I keep getting a strange notification on my Mac and it does look like a virus (Please see attachment). I tried to use an antivirus but it couldn't detect any. I used a Maccleaner to remove all the unused applications but the problem still occurs.

Currently, I'm getting 4 or 5 same notifications everyday.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you subscribed to push notifications from a creepy website. If you use Safari, open its settings dialog and select the Websites tab, then Notifications. Deny notifications from any site you don’t know you want to get them from.

Comment: @LincD.omg, that's exactly it. it's not a creepy website but a website that's selling furnitures and I have no idea why I ended up subscribing to that. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Don't forget to make an answer stating what you did. Then you can accept it later.